# Booting to Linux leads to empty screen and blinking underscore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm dual booting Linux with Windows 10, and after the "Creator's Update" for Win10 my Linux installation stopped booting correctly.  It opened to the Grub prompt, and from there I could direct it to the right directory and boot manually.

While trying to fix the problem, I made it worse.  I ran some commands to attempt to update Grub and reinstall it.

Now I can't boot to Linux or access the grub prompt; when I boot to Linux, it leads me to an empty black screen with nothing but a flashing underscore.  I can't input anything, except Ctrl Alt Del to restart.  If I hold down shift while it's booting up, instead of just a flashing underscore, it says GRUB and a flashing underscore.  It still doesn't let me input any commands.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be, and how I can fix it?

Comment: This happened due to Windows Anniversary (1607) and Creators (1703) Updates , they are deleting linux partitions, as they  doesn't recognize these partitions as valid ones.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix it by booting with a live CD. Then mount the partition that contains your ubuntu installation somewhere, then chroot into it and edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg to correct the menu entry.

So, once you've booted the live CD version (you can boot from an USB drive also) do the following:

- ls /dev - see all sdx drives you got there
- mount /dev/sdx /mnt/ - where sdx is the partition containing your ubuntu root filesystem
- mount --bind /proc /mnt
- mount --bind /dev /mnt
- mount --bind /sys /mnt
- chroot /mnt
- apt-get install --reinstall grub
- vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg - edit the menuentry section to fix your boot

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The Win10 Creators update deletes linux partitions.

Boot from a LiveCD or similar media. and use `testdisk` to restore your partitions.

In most cases, it will boot normally after restoring the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your recommendation and it didn't work.  After loading the OS, rebooting, powering off, reconnecting all the drives, then booting again, I still had the same problem with a blank screen and blinking cursor.  Turns out the problem was in my BIOS.  It has a setting for which drive to boot from.  I have two RAID arrays, so I just told it to use the other RAID array and it worked.